# Oracle Self-dependency type declaration

Tags: oracle

I want to create a customised type in Oracle like below.. can any one tell me how I can achieve this.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE Items_Type FORCE IS OBJECT ( "S.No" VARCHAR2(500) NULL , sub_list "Items_table" NULL  ) NOT FINAL;

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE Items_table IS TABLE OF REF Items_Type;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you could repeat the first `CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE` once again, as it'll fail when executed for the first time. Have a look:

```
SQL> -- statement A
SQL> create or replace type items_type force is object
  2    (sno      varchar2(500) null ,
  3     sub_list items_table   null
  4    ) not final;
  5  /

Warning: Type created with compilation errors.

SQL> show err
Errors for TYPE ITEMS_TYPE:

LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
0/0      PL/SQL: Compilation unit analysis terminated
3/13     PLS-00201: identifier 'ITEMS_TABLE' must be declared
SQL>
SQL> -- statement B
SQL> create or replace type items_table is table of ref items_type;
  2  /

Type created.

SQL> -- statement A, repeated
SQL> create or replace type items_type force is object
  2    (sno      varchar2(500) null ,
  3     sub_list items_table   null
  4    ) not final;
  5  /

Type created.

SQL>
```

Comment: Hi..HOw to create items_table in above query without using "ref".

Comment: As far as I can tell, you can't have mutually dependent objects in both object types. At least one of them must be a *reference*.